# Remote desktop access for windows from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, remote-desktop

I would like to connect to a windows RDP server from my linux machine. This is to access the remote desktop of someone I am helping for something.

The problem when I use rdesktop is that if I login under a certain username from rdesktop, the user is forcefully logged out from the windows computer. And if the user logs in back onto the windows machine, then the rdesktop connection is lost.

What is a good solution so that I can oversee this person's work on the windows machine, from my linux machine?

Comment: You will not be able to do this with RDP. RDP only allows a user to be logged in from one location, including remote locations. You will want to look at VNC or other remote desktop solutions.

Comment: Is this a Remote Desktop server, i.e., does it allow multiple different users to log in at once?  If so, you could probably log in as yourself and then use Remote Assistance to assist the other user.

Answer (score 4):

There are two commonly used protocols for establishing remote control/viewing from desktop to desktop. One is VNC, the other RDP

See [What's the difference between RDP vs VNC?](https://superuser.com/questions/32495/whats-the-difference-between-rdp-vs-vnc)

You need to install a Client on your desktop, and a Server on the desktop you wish to view. Both should follow the same protocol.

It shouldn't matter if these are different softwares on different platforms as long as they both use the same protocol

There are many options on all platforms. I have used [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) on a windows XP machine, accessed from my ubuntu desktop using x11vnc (can't post more links, sorry)

If you are having an issue with one, try another. There are many available.
If you continue to have problems, you are going to have to post a question with some information such as a config file or a log.

Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solutions.
http://www.freerdp.com/
This programs have support for windows rdp protocol.
You just need to configure.

Comment: This won't make any difference.  The problems the OP was having with RDP protocol are independent of the particular RDP client used.