# x11 apps wont run under Windows SSH server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, openssh

I have an SSH server configured on Windows and whenever I connect to it and issue `notepad`, the program does not open:

- I tried both `-X` and `-Y` flags when using SSH, both on the server host system [Windows] and Linux

Comment: X11 is [not supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#not-supported) and IIRC isn't planned to be supported _(I believe there's something on the OpenSSH-WIin32 GitHub, but you'll need to search the [Wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki) and [Issues](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues) pages)_

Comment: If you want to access windows apps from a remote system, you should look at [remote desktop or VNC](https://superuser.com/questions/32495/whats-the-difference-between-rdp-vs-vnc).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is not an X11 app. Overall, the Windows graphics system is not X11-based at all.